# Set an HTML table with filters and sorting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, filtering

I am looking for a script that allows me to insert in an html table the possibility of filtering data with the same (or almost) elasticity that for example Excel offers, that is the possibility of filtering certain elements even on multiple fields, the possibility of order in ascending and descending order and also the possibility of filtering all elements, for example greater or less than a certain number.

Is there something a thing like that?

Thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: Can you try this package `react-data-table-component`

Comment: React hasn't been tagged in this question, so it might be overkill to recommend a React package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Datatables is the solution:**

Url: https://datatables.net/

You have multiple plugins/extensions for this... You can do everything you imagine...

**Select by column value:**

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

**Search in each column:**

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  So is it possible to make an HTML table where each field has a menu like this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/bs4ub0olhrxt8iu/IMG_4298.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Dani. I saw your advice "Select by value column" and are almost close to what I need. Unfortunately I didn't understand how you can select more than 1 value for each column because in that example I can only select 1 value for each column, while I need control boxes to select all the values you want to filter for each column. Finally, the possibility of filtering for greater values, minor or other than others. However, thank you for these advices!

Answer (score 2):

By the description of your issue I would suggest you to take a look at the [Datatables website](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom) or in the [Tabulator website](http://tabulator.info/). Both work pretty well and are very easy to get up and running.